# how to build connection between independent watch app and companion iOS app?

Tags: xcode11, watchos-6

I created a project with "iOS App with Watch App" template in XCode11(beta5), the project setting item - "Supports Running Without iOS App Installation" has been selected by default. The official doc shows that independent watch app can still use WatchConnectivity framework to transfer data, so I did it but it didn't work on simulator. I captured the error info with "Companion app is not installed". But it works When I uncheck "Supports Running Without iOS App Installation" (become dependent watch app).

How can I use WatchConnectivity to communicate between Watch & iPhone simulator when watch app is independent?

Comment: Did you got solution for this, Since I am able to send data from phone to watch, but, Unable to pass data from watch to phone. If you got fix, Can you share code here?